# constants not working when mapperclass has multiple methods with the return type of the constant

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following mapper interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {
        MapperClassA.class
})
public interface SourceTargetMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "allowed", constant = "Boolean.FALSE")
    Target toTarget(final Source );
}
```

MapperClassA has the following methods:

```
public static boolean isAllowed(final String id) {
    // implementation
}

public static boolean isSafe(final String id) {
    // implementation
}
```

when I run a clean install I get the following error:

> SourceTargetMapper.java: Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping
>   constant '"Boolean.FALSE"' to java.lang.Boolean: boolean
>   MapperClassA.isAllowed(java.lang.String id), boolean
>   MapperClassA.isSafe(java.lang.String id).

If I add a @Named to the two methods then the code compiles just fine. However, I don't understand why it even looks for those methods in MapperClassA to begin with. According to the MapStruct documentation:

> When the target type is a primitive or a boxed type, the String value
>   is taken literal. ... In all other cases, constant or default values are
>   subject to type conversion either via built-in conversions or the
>   invocation of other mapping methods in order to match the type
>   required by the target property.

In this case 'allowed' is a Boolean property in the Target class. So it should just take the String value right? rather than try to invoke a method in a mapper.

Anyone who can explain why it doesn't just use the 'Boolean.FALSE'?

Answer (score 1):

try

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring" )
public interface SourceTargetMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "allowed", constant = "false")
    Target toTarget(final Source );
}
```

so without your mapping methods.

Problem

1. the user can override the defaults in MapStruct. So MapStruct will first look for mapping methods that fulfil the criteria : boolean -> String. Then it will try type conversion (internal).
2. MapStruct 1.3 introduced plain constants. So MapStruct will recognise your "true" and put it as literal in the generated mapper.